# Access to postgresql remotely on windows

Tags: postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL version 8.3.19 on windows server 2003. After configuration, I can access locally (from a php script) but not remotely (from another similar php script, from another machine).
1) NAT is configured and tested for the port 5432
2) Firewall authorises the application
3) I set the pg_hba.conf file:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

4) I set the postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

5) I created a role with pgAdminIII for the access from an application. I declared him superuser (just for the tests) and named him TOTO
6) My local script is:

```
$con=pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 user=TOTO password=PW dbname=test")
```

7) My remote script is:

```
$con=pg_connect("host=myhostname port=5432 user=TOTO password=PW dbname=test")
```

I don't see what I could forget. Could you light me ?

Comment: I don't know ;-( I tried pg_last_error but returns blank. As the reply is long, I suppose to have a timeout.

Comment: did you try connecting to the postgres remotely by command line?

Comment: Give me the prodedure. I tried telnet myhostname 5432. The reply is time out

Comment: `psql -U TOTO -h myhostname -p 5432 -W` if you are getting timeout, NAT, F/W, DNS or routing is not configured properly I guess

Comment: This is the case ! May we continue or is it another subject ?

Comment: I discovered in the log file of the server the following message: "database TOTO doesn't exist" : are you sure of the syntax ?

Comment: Now try with `psql -U TOTO -h myhostname -p 5432 -W -d test` or however your database is called. But if you have this message in the log then you're able to connect to the server.

Comment: connection time out BUT nothing in the log file !

Comment: I am sorry but my discovery is wrong: I tried again and there is no inscription in the log file. Therefore, for you, the problem is in NAT or F/W ?

Comment: ShieldsUp application tells me the port 5432 is open

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting timeouts then as mask8 says it's probably firewall configuration problems. See if you can connect to your target IP from the server itself. Also enable connection logging in postgresql's config.

Oh, and unless you really have to use that version, install 9.1, 8.3 is due for retirement fairly soon.

Comment: I suppose by psql -U TOTO -h localhost -p 5432 -W -d test ? if yes then I can

Comment: Download from EnterpriseDB ? pgInstaller 9.1.x doesn't exist on postgresql.org !

Comment: Sure, EnterpriseDB do the windows packaging. Don't use "-h localhost" in your test, use "-h 123.123.123.123" or whatever the external IP address is.

Comment: with -h 192.168.1.1 I can connect, with -h 82.x.x.x I cannot. I tested on the server itself and from another machine on the lan.

Comment: Assuming the setting listed above, that suggests 82.x is firewalled somehow. You can check what ports PostgreSQL has open if there is any doubt: http://www.petri.co.il/quickly_find_local_open_ports.htm

Comment: the opened porst is 5432. 82.x.x.x is the external IP address of the router. At this step, I don't know what is wrong:nat,F/W, postgresql setting, ...

Comment: Well if 192... is the address that Pg is supposed to listen on then your problem is definitely in the network setup

Comment: No. See at the beginning. Pg listen an external client. pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf seem correct.

Comment: No, not your PostgreSQL network configuration. The problem is in the setup of your actual network - firewall, router etc.